# Getting IServiceProvider as a Dependency to get Optional Dependencies in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, anti-patterns

Is it a bad practice to get `IServiceProvider` injected to a service class, as a means to get optional dependencies in ASP.NET Core 2.0? Does this break [Explicit Dependency Principal](http://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/)?

I've a class which requires an Optional Service, EventBus. If the EventBus is registered, I want the service class to publish an event, if not simply ignore it.

```
public class SomeService {
   private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

   public SomeService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
      _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
   }

   public SomeAction() {
      var eventBus = _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IEventBus)) as IEventBus;
      if (eventBus != null) {
           eventBus.publish("SomeAction Happened!");
      }
   }
}
```

I can't see how to create optional dependencies with the built in IoC Container of ASP.NET Core 2.0.

EDIT: Any suggestions how to implement optional dependencies in ASP.NET Core? Or any other strategy to get the same effect without the anti-pattern?

Comment: That's called the service locator and yes, it's an anti-pattern that you should avoid

Answer (score 1):

It would not be considered optional if it is required directly by the method in order for it to function correctly.

It should be explicitly injected as a dependency

```
public class SomeService {
    private readonly IEventBus eventBus;

    public SomeService(IEventBus eventBus) {
        this.eventBus = eventBus;
    }

    public SomeAction() {
        if (eventBus != null) {
            eventBus.publish("SomeAction Happened!");
        }

        //...
    }
}
```

otherwise consider passing it explicitly to the method as an *optional* dependency

```
public SomeAction(IEventBus eventBus = null) {
    if (eventBus != null) {
        eventBus.publish("SomeAction Happened!");
    }

    //...
}
```

> ### The Explicit Dependencies Principle states:
>
> Methods and classes should ***explicitly require*** (typically through method parameters or
>   constructor parameters) ***any collaborating objects they need in order
>   to function correctly***.

*emphasis mine*

Injecting `IServiceProvider` is debated as an anti-pattern as it follows a service locator pattern.

There are some exceptions for example if the dependent class is being also used as a factory.

Answer (score 0):

Injecting `IServiceProvider` is an implementation of the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). Prevent from doing this. Neither should dependencies be [optional](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97#Optional-dependencies). This introduces complexity. Instead, use the [Null Object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern). Making the dependency *required*, simplifies the consumer and its test.

In other words, `SomeService` should look as follows:

```
public class SomeService {
   private readonly IEventBus _bus;

   public SomeService(IEventBus bus) {
      _bus = bus ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bus));
   }

   public SomeAction() {
       eventBus.publish("SomeAction Happened!");
   }
}
```

In your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) you use a `NullEventBus` implementation in case no real implementation exists. This should be as easy as this:

```
public class NullEventBus : IEventBus
{
    public void publish(string message) {
        // do nothing.
    }
}
```

Since this implementation does nothing, it can be injected into all consumers.